# How do you remove \r from a string?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I don't know why but the string returned from the source comes with **"\r"** at the end, it looks like this, **"String\r"**, but when I print it in the debug window, it only sees it as **"String"**, but when I used it for comparing using `isEqualToString:`, it always returns as false even though on the debug window they are both similar

Comment: Are you sure it's not `\r`?  The direction of the slash does matter.

Comment: just a typo sir sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This.

```
NSString *string = @"Whats Going on\r";
NSString *result = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

or the simple way as we used to replace a particuler string into string. like

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@" "];
```

Comment: string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@" "]; -> I tried this before asking here but doesn't work

Fortunately, the trimming did the job, thanks sir, I'll be able to accept it in 3 mins

Comment: @BryanPosas - Probably "ByReplacing" failed because you got the slash direction mucked up.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following method

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target 
                                    withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

Example :

```
NSString *string = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r"
                                                           withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a client-server app and haven't met any problems with `\r` in the end of data transmitted. But you are talking about `/r` I suppose, so here it goes.

Since it is only in the end of your string and you wouldn't want to remove any other occurrences of it in your strings (as proposed above):

```
yourStr = [yourStr substringToIndex:[yourStr length]-2]
```

Now in case of a type error, you do the same, but this time you remove only one character from the string, since `\r` is an escape character and is only one char `'\r'`:

```
yourStr = [yourStr substringToIndex:[yourStr length]-1]
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] did the trick for me, but I never knew \r is only 1 character, so thanks for that, unfortunately i still can't upvote

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `\r` from your NSString, but maybe better make sure it does not reach your NSStrings in the first place. If you are reading a text file you may get them, because the source has this strange idea about end of line. Like Excel 16 (!) on macOS, when exporting a .csv file. I did choose UTF8 as export text format, but ended up with `\r` at the end of strings. You can see that the file format is `[dos]` when you read and save the file with VIM, or, issue the command `:set ff?` and vim will tell you `fileformat=dos`. Change the file format to unix: `:set ff=unix` and things are fine, and `\r` are gone.

Solution source: https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/hu3jlszfrf-change-dos-to-unix-text-file-format-in-vim